# How to Pass input Field Data from Modal to the Container in react-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is what I am using:

> ```
> <Modal
>     visible = {this.props.visible}
>     animationType="slide"
>     transparent
>     onRequestClose={() => {}} >
>          <TextInput 
>            style = {styles.inputBox}
>            ref = {this.props.destinatinon} />
>    </Modal>
> ```

and in the Container

> 

```
 <ExampleModal
       destination = {this.state.destination} >
     </ExampleModal>
```

I don't know how to pass data from Modal to Parent Component. Any kind of Tutorial or link is fine. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume that your Modal is filed separately in `/components/MyModal` to generalize things.

You can make your Modal call a function that you passed by props every time input text is changed. Here's a simple callback logic you can use.

**Avoid using refs as much as you can.**

```
import MyModal from '../components/MyModal';
...
class Home extends Component {
  onInputChanged = (changedText) => {
    console.log('This is the changed text: ', changedText);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ...
        <MyModal onInputChanged={this.onInputChanged} .../>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// components folder
class MyModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        visible = {this.props.visible}
        animationType="slide"
        transparent
        onRequestClose={() => {}} >
           <TextInput 
             style = {styles.inputBox}
             onChangeText={(changedText) => this.props.onInputChanged(changedText)} />
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

**Side Note:** You can define MyModal [stateless](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) to make things a bit cleaner.

Comment: Glad to hear that!